# how can import my number to telegram channel

Tags: excel, import, numbers, telegram

I have lots of numbers in excel and I like to import to my telegram channel .who can help me how can do this ?
so I have channel in telegram and I like to add member on it.

Answer (score 1):

i found my answer 
the easy way is download excel to contact in iOS then backup number and download in excel then add numbers to this list and upload to phone .now you can add new number to telegram channel 
have a nice day